# Разбить строку с помощью символов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Как разбить текст с помощью регулярного выражения?
Пример текста

> У старинушки три сына: старший — умный был детина, средний сын и так и
>   сяк, младший — вовсе был дурак

как разделить слова с помощью символов: пробел, запятая, двоеточие, тире, точка с запятой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\pP` - символьный класс знаков препинания
`\s` - символьный класс пробельных символов

```
$str = 'У старинушки три сына: старший — умный был детина, средний сын и так и сяк, младший — вовсе был дурак';

$arr = array_filter(preg_split('~[\pP\s]~u', $str));

var_dump($arr);
```